# How to add rows in R that subtract 2 other rows based on common variables?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is structured like the sample below. Each combination of `date`, `market`, `gender`, and `age` has 3 observations of type, "New", "Reac" and "Active". For each of these groups, I'd like to add a 4th row, which maintains the same `date`, `market`, `gender`, and `age` variables, but has a different `type`, and the `cust` and `orders` columns are generated by subtracting the type=New `cust` and `orders` values from the type=Active `cust` and `order` values.

For example, I would like to go from this:

```
date    market    gender    type    age    cust     orders

Apr-18  UK        Female    New     U20    1000     1500
Apr-18  UK        Female    Reac    U20    1000     1750
Apr-18  UK        Female    Active  U20    3000     7000
```

To this:

```
date    market    gender    type    age    cust     orders

Apr-18  UK        Female    New     U20    1000     1500
Apr-18  UK        Female    Reac    U20    1000     1750
Apr-18  UK        Female    Active  U20    3000     7000
Apr-18  UK        Female    Old     U20    2000     5500
```

So I have subtracted the type=New row from the type=Active row and stored the new `cust` and `orders` numbers in a 4th row, which has type=Old.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `group_by` `date`, `market`, `gender` and `age`, subtract `cust` and `orders` and add `type = 'old'`. We can bind these new rows to the original dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(date, market, gender, age) %>%
  summarise(cust = cust[type=='Active'] - cust[type=='New'], 
            orders = orders[type=='Active'] - orders[type=='New'], 
            type = 'old') %>%
  bind_rows(df)

#  date   market gender age    cust orders type  
#  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct> <int>  <int> <chr> 
#1 Apr-18 UK     Female U20    2000   5500 old   
#2 Apr-18 UK     Female U20    1000   1500 New   
#3 Apr-18 UK     Female U20    1000   1750 Reac  
#4 Apr-18 UK     Female U20    3000   7000 Active
```